# How to call a function from args in a vector?

Tags: c++

I want to call a function taking 2 parameters but I want to call this function without actually writing `f(arg1, arg2)`. For example I have a function:

```cpp
float f(float a, float b) {
    // ...
}
```

And I want to call it with but from a vector:

```cpp
std::vector args = {1.f, 1.f}; // arguments stored in vector
f(args[0], args[1]); // call the function
```

In this example it works but in fact I don't know how many args there are so I want to do something like:

```cpp
std::vector args = {...};
f(args...); // pass all elements as arguments
```

Comment: What's wrong with simply taking an `const std::vector &` as parameter?

Comment: Or taking a (half-open) range like a lot of the standard function do.

Comment: @churill Yes it would be the solution but I also need to std::bind my function

Comment: @Jojolatino And where is the problem with this?

Comment: @churill If the function takes a std::vector, how can I bind the second parameter (for example) in the vector?

Comment: @Jojolatino Not sure what you mean. When using a vector there is not second parameter. Only a vector with two (or more) elements.